# Using values in a column to update other values in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have the below dataframe

| Country | Year turns green | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 | 2028 | 2029 | 2030 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 2024 | 1085 | 1120 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| France | 2026 | 1230 | 1845 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 | 1600 |
| Brazil | 2026 | 1115 | 1090 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 | 1350 |
| Italy | 2028 | 1455 | 1720 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 | 1630 |
| Australia | 2023 | 1095 | 1360 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 | 1285 |

I need to take the year that each country turns green and update the value to 0 from that year onwards. E.g. Germany turns green in 2024 so all values from 2024 onwards for Germany will be 0.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I can not figure out the fastest way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def zero_turns_green_func(row):
    year_turns_green = row.loc['Year turns green']
    row.loc[year_turns_green :] = 0
    return row
df.apply(zero_turns_green_func, axis = 1)
```